# Moving 15,000+ images from Shared host to VPS

Tags: vps, shared-hosting, file-transfer

I've just finished up a script I've written for my website. The VPS is purchased, now I don't know what the effective method to be able to move `15,000+` images I have on my shared host to a new VPS (separate reseller hosts).

I only thought of one, download all of the images to my hard drive and then upload to the VPS via `FTP`, however I do not have decent speeds `~160kb/s` and upload speed is roughly `~60/70kb/s`.

What would be the most effective method to transfer `15,000+` images from a shared host to a brand new VPS?

Comment: Do you hae shell access to your shared host, and what OS is your VPS?

Comment: tar/zip/rar/whatever 'em up and upload that bundle. Un tar/zip/rar on the other end.

Comment: I do not have shell access on my shared host. Both are Linux.

Comment: But you do have shell access on your VPS, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could do an ftp from your shared host direct to your vps

otherwise you could also do a recursive wget to download via http direct to your vps, for more info take a look here: http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/wget/

Answer (score 2):

I'd strongly suggest you don't introduce a 3rd party (your computer) as it will most likely drastically increase the time taken. The shared host and VPS will have **much** faster transfer speeds between each other.

Why can't you simply access the shared hosting from your VPS?

Just use the same method - ftp/scp/sftp/http/whatever from your vps.

If you give a little more detail on what you mean by "download all of the images [from my shared host] to my hard drive" or who your shared host is then we can probably give a better answer.

Comment: Sorry. When I said hard drive, I meant my computer.

Comment: "my computer" and "my harddrive" are pretty much interchangeable in the context. My advice remains the same :-)

Comment: Ok my computer means my MacBook. Does that help? :-)

Comment: No sorry. What I'm suggesting in my current answer is that you "download" from your vps. I don't know how you would "download" from your macbook, but you seem to have an idea already. There's no reason why you can't do that from your vps so pretend your vps is your laptop. If you update your question with  how you normally access the "shared host" e.g. "ftp" or "a webui by my provider" (not credentials) then we can clarify a better answer.

Comment: I was saying if I download the images from a FTP client to my MacBook.

Comment: Aha. So why not download the images by ftp straight onto the VPS?

Answer (score 1):

Most effective method would probably be to either upload them in batches (compress them into usable chunks and upload a bit at a time) or take your collection to another location and use their connection; a business friend with high speed, maybe a local B&N/Starbucks/Panera if you're in the States, etc. and upload over a nice book or drink. Something like that...that's what I'd first suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Id ask for a shell account from each provider explaining you need to copy files from one server to another.

You can then use rsync with -av --stats --progress  -e ssh folder_to_copy user@remotehost:.

This will let you copy the files in the most efficient manner and allow for you to resume if it failed for whatever reason.

Comment: I agree with you, rsync through ssh is the best way to securely transfer those files.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your shared server and VPS support FXP, you can connect those two servers using ftp client and transfer the data between them(no need through your computer).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol

> File eXchange Protocol (FXP) and (FXSP) is a method of data transfer which uses FTP to transfer data from one remote server to another (inter-server) without routing this data through the client's connection.
>   Blockquote